# mysql date comparison only comparing year

Tags: mysql, date

I am running a simple query in mysql 5.1.73

```
SELECT i.start_date
FROM Injuries i
WHERE i.start_date>='2014-16-08'
```

My problem is that this only returns dates on or after '2015-01-01'

i.start_date is a date field. I know there are records with dates between '2014-08-16' and '2015-01-01' so i'm not sure why they are being omitted.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'2014-16-08'` is the wrong format. It should be `'2014-08-16'` which is `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: Speak for yourself. 8th of Sedecimber is my favourite day of the year!

Comment: Wow, I am in awe of the fact that i spent 20 minutes trying to solve this before posting and didn't realise they were the wrong way round.